# how to find execution time function/method in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, execution

I have mvc5 project, some of my code is running slowly, but I do not know where the problem is. How do I see the runtime of each class or method that is running on a request in vs17

Comment: Have you tried to use the Performance Profiler in Visual Studio?

Comment: You can use an IL weaving library like Fody to accomplish this. https://github.com/Fody/MethodTimer

Comment: I tried but I couldn't. I try again @Kzrystof

Comment: Was there any error? What went wrong?